# HTTPS - Mvc3 - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, https

I have a requirement where the site needs to allways open in https mode (other than local development). This is internal app.

When i run the site with web.config entry to true for https, it looks like the site goes into circular motion and repeats the request again and again.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        //make sure that the remote site opens in https mode.
        bool isSSL = false;
        bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ApplicationKeys.IsSSLRequired], out isSSL);
        if (isSSL && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

    }
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);

        //wire up Unity IoC
        container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityBootstrapper.ConfigureContainer(container);
        EntityMapper.MapEntities();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        //wire up Unity Controller Factory
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new UnityControllerFactory());
    }
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already leveraging web.config to drive this functionality, I would suggest that you utilize [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

You can set up a rule to redirect non-HTTPS traffic to HTTPS.  See this thread for the configuration:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149780.aspx

With that in place, you can further improve your development experience by leveraging [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) to enable the rule when you deploy to your production environment.

Comment: I have removed the code from global file and created a rule in web.config. When i use http, i get error message "The page isn't redirecting properly". Here is the rule:

<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect to https">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.domain.com/Study/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>

Comment: I'm guessing you're in an infinite redirect loop because you didn't specify to redirect to HTTPS.  The url attribute should look something like "https://dev.domain.com/Study{R:1}" given what you supplied in your comment.

Comment: @learning hey, sorry, i just realized that SO converted my URI to an actual link instead of the text I intended.  Sorry for the confusion.  It should be `"https://dev.domain.com/Study{R:1}"`.

Comment: https from my comment above got removed due to some rule on this site. I have put https on the site and it worked for me. Thanks for your help.

I haven't received email notifications for the help threads. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @learning... i'm not sure what you're referring to regarding help threads.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx) which supports SSL to host your site.

Answer (score 0):

In your Global.asax:

```cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    bool isSSL = false;
    bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ApplicationKeys.IsSSLRequired], out isSSL);
    if (isSSL && !Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
}
```

Comment: This results in page isn't redirecting properly error. Just like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Is HttpContext.Current.Request available at Application_Start() ?